# Ant build fails because of insufficient permissions Windows 10

Tags: xml, build, ant, windows-10

My build.xml file fails on this target tag.

```
<property name="composer" value="C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/"/>

<target name="composerInstall"
        unless="composerInstall.done"
        description="Installs composer dependencies">
    <exec executable="${composer}" taskname="composer">
        <arg value="install"/>
    </exec>
    <property name="composerInstall.done" value="true"/>
</target>
```

with this error...

```
C:\Users\me\spaceballs\build.xml:29: Execute failed:
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\" (in directory "C:\Users\me\spaceballs"): 
CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
```

I am running windows 10 home edition with Docker Toolbox installed. The commands "docker-compose up" and "composer install" work fine from the command line and I have tried adjusting the permissions on that bin directory in hopes of fixing this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to build using this target instead...

```
<target name="composerInstall"
        unless="composerInstall.done"
        description="Installs composer dependencies">
    <exec executable="${php}">
        <arg value="${composer}"/>
        <arg value="install"/>
    </exec>
    <property name="composerInstall.done" value="true"/>
</target>
```

Added this target that defines $(php)

```
<target name="php-check">
    <condition property="php" value="php">
    <not>
        <isset property="${php}"/>
    </not>
    </condition>
</target>
```

the composer was defined as...

```
<property name="composer" value="${basedir}/composer.phar"/>
```